Truncated CMDT getInstance()
I am curious - when using a long text field for a CMDT and you run the getInstance() method on the CMDT to pull all of the values for a specific record...is there a character limit for the getInstance() method? I found that when I just getInstance() the long text area field gets truncated but when I a full query on the CMDT the full field values are returned. Is there any documentation on this?
IE:
testData = MyCustomMetaData__cmdt.getInstance(mdtName);
system.debug('testData returns truncated field__c values: '  + testData);
system.debug('query returns full long text field__c values: ' + [SELECT Id, Fields__c FROM MyCustomMetaData__cmdt WHERE Label =:mdtName]);


Yes, there is a limit: 255 characters. It's stated in the documentation (emphasis mine):

Use this method to explicitly retrieve custom metadata type information at the user level. Only the first 255 characters of any field in a custom metadata type record are returned. Therefore, fields such as long text fields can be truncated. If you want all the field data from a custom metadata type record, use a SOQL query.

That's why to get the full content of long text area field you need a SOQL. By the way, in this case the query counts against the governor limit

Yes, there is a 255 character limit on long text fields retrieved by getInstance. This is in the documentation.

getInstance(developerName)
...
Usage
Use this method to explicitly retrieve custom metadata type information at the user level. Only the first 255 characters of any field in a custom metadata type record are returned. Therefore, fields such as long text fields can be truncated. If you want all the field data from a custom metadata type record, use a SOQL query.

